# parseInt of ranged(31-40) string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, parseint

I'm not able to convert integer of ranged string. I have a age group of 21-30, 31-40,41-50 etc, I have to convert selected string and send to server.
I have tried with parseInt method but not working.
Below is the code,

```
var ageSelected = '31-40';
parseInt(ageSelected) //Output is only first number 31 NOT 31-40
```

Please anybody have idea about this, please help me

Comment: `-` is not an int use `parseInt(ageSelected.split('-')[0])` for first number `parseInt(ageSelected.split('-')[1])` for second number

Comment: @guradio Ok then how do I convert for ranging numbers like 1-10, 11-20 etc.. is there any other way to convert

Comment: what should be the output from `31-40` input, since 31-40 is not a valid integer?

Comment: see comment above..split them into 2 numbers then convert

Comment: you cant send `31-40` as an integer because it is not one. If you just have to send this variable as `31-40` is has to be the string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System don't understand what is `31-40`. It can't be a valid integer. You can either send it as a String to the server and process there or send as two separate integers.

```
var ageSelected = '31-40';
parseInt(ageSelected.split("-")[0]) //start age
parseInt(ageSelected.split("-")[1]) // end age
```

Comment: @Suresh, Can't we append - by two integers and send to server

Comment: That will again become a String that you have processed.

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar why you cant send that as a string?

Comment: @Sures.. Ok thank u, it will become again string only.. I will talk with web team, will try to send as a string.. Thank you Suresh